# Java Spring Injection of member fields

Tags: java, spring

```
@Component
public class TrackCoach implements Coach {
  private int integerVal;
}
```

When I was using XML configs, I used to easily do something like:

```
<property name="integerVal" value="174"/>
```

How do I achieve something with annotations?

Comment: in which class is this emal property

Comment: @Johny, thats just a generic example, ill fix it

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component
public class TrackCoach implements Coach {
  @Value("${integerVal}")
  private int integerVal;
}
```

This will inject the value to that variable.
Inside your `application.properties` file
add a new property inside

`integerVal=174`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the property in a properties file like

```
 yourIntegerValue=12345
```

The you can use this property like

```
@Component
public class TrackCoach implements Coach {
  @Value("${yourIntegerValue}")
  private int integerVal;
}
```